# displaying XML to html after retrieving from SQL 2014 XML column

Tags: c#, sql, xml

using C#, need code snippet that will query column containing xml data and write data to an external XML file.
There after style the xml file and show it in a html div Tag.

Comment: i have reviews the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code would look something like the code below.  You need to modify the connection string and SQL as required.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication58
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connStr = "Enter Your Conneciton String Here";
            string SQL = "Select XML_COL_NAME from table1";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, connStr);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            dt.WriteXml("filename");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: jdweng, i just noticed something with the retrieval of the data.. the tags all change to &lt; and &gt; around the tagged info and when stored its stored normally with its tags in palce, any ideas in changing this?

Comment: See webpage https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references